# You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin on this server in CentOS7 VPS server

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, centos, vps

I have installed `Apache`, `PHP`, `MariaDB` and `PHPMyAdmin` in my `VPS CentOS7`. But when I access PHPMyAdmin on

```
http://my-server-ip-here/phpMyAdmin
```

It's giving this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin on this server.
```

My configuration, `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
#
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip my-server-ip-here
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
    # Deny from All
     Allow from my-server-ip-here
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip my-server-ip-here
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     #Deny from All
     Allow from my-server-ip-here
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add your IP or range under the Allow section in the `phpMyAdmin.conf` to be able to access your phpMyAdmin remotely. A restart of the `httpd` service is required after amending the `phpMyAdmin.conf`.

If your IP is `123.456.789.1` then:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip my-server-ip-here
       Require ip ::1
       Require ip 123.456.789.1 #add your IP
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
    # Deny from All
     Allow from my-server-ip-here
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from 123.456.789.1 #add your IP
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: So you are connecting from localhost?

Comment: No am accessing using IP like this http://123.456.789.1/phpMyAdmin. And installed softwares using SSH.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you need to add your IP to the allow, not your servers IP. To get your IP google "what is my ip".

Comment: If I am accessing in web, I have to add my server IP right?

Comment: No, you have to add whatever IP(s) you are connecting from.

Comment: So, if am accessing phpmyadmin from your system or from others system, I have to add all IPs?

Comment: Well your other option is to change the rules to Allow from all IPs but that is not as secure. You could combine that with HTTP Authentication to get some access control back however.